# Shoot through problem in 3-phase BLDC controller circuit

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, shoot-through

I have designed a 3-phase controller for a BLDC motor. I am checking one side of the bridge with a Pico-scope for shoot through. The wave-forms below are indicating that i am getting shoot through, and this waveform is the same for all 3 legs of the 3-phase inverter. The probes of the Pico-scope are connected to the gate of the FET's but I am not sure if this is correct as the high side Probe its not VGS. I think i would need a potential difference probe for the high side FETs. How can I check if this is actually shoot through or not, all three sides of the bridge give me the exact same waveform?  is this waveform showing shoot through or is this not shoot through?

[image: 1 side of the bridge]
[image: RED waveform indicates high side, Blue low side of the bridge]

[image: Zoomed in]

Comment: Put a 0.1 ohm resistor between the source of Q2 and ground. The voltage across the resistor will be a measure of the current through the transistors, and will make shoot-through quite obvious.

Comment: Do the drive signals to U1 and U2 have any dead time between them?  You may want to look at the section titled "IPM Dead Time and Propagation Delay Specifications" in the '3120 data sheet, pg. 27.

Comment: Hi, no they do not have dead time and both optos have a 200ns propagation delay. Does the charging and discharging resistors not implement the dead time, as the FET turns off faster than it turns on?

Comment: You really need dead time even if there's theoretically a slight dead time from the different gate drive resistors. Transistors have an inherent switching time, and ramp up/down, and with higher voltage gate drives tend to stay on more than you might expect. My own experiments with this have shown me you really need 500ns dead time to be certain of not shooting through. Tbh, this is not a good gate driver for a beginner, unless you're making very high voltage drives you're better off with combined high and low gate drives with integrated protection against shoot through.

Comment: My favorite gate drives are on semi fan7888 and infineon 6edl04 series. They seem pretty robust. You might need higher current for that MOSFET, fairly large Cin, but there are plenty of options. They also use bootstrap so you don't need an isolated high side power supply... Apologies of you really do need the isolation!

Comment: I am trying to build for high power, but this is only a prototype so I can test, how can I achieve this dead time, isit done in code